# How do i link and sync my ios app to cloudantnosqlite?

Tags: ios, ibm-cloud

Hey i have been using xcode for a month, so please bear with me... I am using ibm's bluemix as backend for my app. Cloudant is the cloud database service that they provide. At this conjecture I need to pass data first to the cloud and then replicate it locally in core data. I just cant seem to figure out how to do this at this point, Could somebody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I did understand right: you add data onto the Cloudant database in Bluemix and need to push it out to your mobile data store on the ios devices?

The challenge you face: Cloudant has no idea where the device are and if they are reachable/connected

The steps you take are:

- Update the Cloudant database
- Send a PUSH notification using the push notification service in Bluemix
- Your iOS application needs to be configured to wake up on arrival of such a push notification
- Execute a sync as described in the documentation (link in previous answer)

That should do the trick. Let us know how it works

Comment: Thanks for the guidelines, I am still working on implementing it.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry for this vague answer but based on your question this is best I can do you.  It should get you in the right direction at least.
https://github.com/cloudant/CDTDatastore